# passing id of a nested resource for deleting a file in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a listing with many photos. So I am using a nested resource. But the issue now am facing is that I am unable to delete a single photo. I can see that its because the photo id is nil.

**Here is my photos_controller**

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController


  before_action :set_listing

  def index
    @photos = @listing.photos.all

  end

  def create
    @photo = @listing.photos.new(photo_params)
    if @photo.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @photo = @listing.photos.find(params[:id])
    @photo.destroy
    redirect_to photos_url, notice: 'Photo was successfully destroyed.'
  end

  private



  def set_listing
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
  end

  def photo_params
    params.require(:photo).permit(:image, :remove_image)
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
 resources :listings do
    resources :photos, only: [:index, :create, :destroy]
   end
```

In my index page I have a div to display the images via partial
index.html.erb

**create.html.erb**

```
$("#photos div").append("<%= j render(@photo) %>")
```

Here is my photo partial

**_photo.html.erb**

```
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading-preview">
                <%= image_tag photo.image_url(:thumb) %>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
          <span class="pull-right">
            <%= link_to "#", remote: true, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} do %>
      <i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i>
                <% end %>
          </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

In the _photo.html.erb I also tried

```
<%= link_to listing_photo_path(photo.id), remote: true, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} do %>
```

But am getting this error while loading the index page

> No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"photos", :id=>nil,
>   :listing_id=>1} missing required keys: [:id]

All photos do have id and can easily delete it if I hardcode the id for photos. Can someone tell me what am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a nested resource in you route, like you have, there will be two levels of `identifying ids` as follow:

```
resources :listings do
  resources :photos, only: [:index, :create, :destroy]
end
```

a typical url for the nested photo (if you check `rake routes`) will be as follow:

```
/listings/:listing_id/photos/:id
```

Which means that you need to provide upto two identifiers(`listing_id` and `id`-which is the photo id)

so, in your link to the destroy method, all you need to do is include this as follow:

```
<%= link_to listing_photo_path(listing_id: @listing.id, id: photo.id), remote: true, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} do %>
```

Comment: worked...Thanks mate. I thought about it before but I saw that its already getting the listing_id correctly..so I didnt passed that..

Answer (score 1):

You should also provide your `Listing` id, as you have nested resources:

```
<%= link_to listing_photo_path(@listing, photo) # etc. %>
```

or simply:

```
<%= link_to [@listing, photo] # etc %>
```